# Angular JS breaks in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, ipad, angularjs

I've written an application that works great in the desktop browser but breaks in Safari.
Does Angularjs support the iPad's native browser?

I've been googling and can't find anything that isn't related to PhoneGap.  It's just javascript in a browser isn't it?

How do you even debug this?

## Solution

I was using reserved words like `delete` in my services which broke safari and **not** chrome.  On both desktop and tablet safari is broken but chrome works.  I have to switch the reserved words to something like `remove`.

http://paste.laravel.com/NNB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the iPad go Settings > Safari > Developer > Enable Debugging

On top of safari you'll get a "1 Error" or "19 Errors" and when you click the bar it will list out the console for you.

Comment: If only this still worked. you're now required to have the latest version of desktop safari to debug, which is only available on a Mac. /facepalm

Comment: ::breaks into tears::

Answer (score 2):

Instead of renaming the method you may change the way of calling it. For instance `service['delete']()` instead of
`service.delete()`

Same problem exists with method *finally* of promise object (older IEs even crash on call `promise.finally()`).

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS 1.0.7 works fine on my iPad (first edition) with IOS 5.whatever.the.last.supported.version.was! It's surprisingly quick, too, although Mobile Safari crashes with depressing regularity when it runs out of memory! This happens on many other web sites, though.

Comment: Do you mean you had a service named 'delete', or a 'delete' function, or what? (Still, thanks for the tip!)

Comment: My service had a method named `delete`: http://paste.laravel.com/NNB I have to do some sort of mass Find and Replace in my project now :/