# Odd Safari issue using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

This issue is only happening with the current version of Safari on Mac.  (Older versions of Safari may be affected, but are not needed for this)

A generic 500 error is getting returned every time for Safari only.

*There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.*

All other browser I can test with return successfully having *data* be the expected chunk of HTML to display.

Here is my ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        async: true,  //Added based on internet suggestions
        type: "POST",
        url: '../Provider/SaveAddress',
        data: buildAddressJsonData(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {               
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            DisplayErrorMessage(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
```

I added in `async: true` based on some others saying that fixed the problem.  I even tried modifying the response serverside with `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");` as that was also suggested.

I've also confirmed that `buildAddressJsonData()` is providing proper json, here is an example.

`{"IsRequired":"1","AddressIndex":"1","AddressLine1":"IBM","AddressLine2":"123 Upper St","AddressLine3":"Unit 14","City":"My Town","Id":"481c40d3-4a38-492b-880e-33b16021fb69","Lk_AddressTypeId":"d2316e7e-b2df-4274-9757-1ae5aa171f68","Lk_CountryId":"13c9fb13-8f50-438e-890a-63e6f1f4cd29","Lk_StateId":"0894fa8a-8d6b-43fc-89ec-e16ba915b6a4","SendMail":1}`

This is all housed in an ASP.Net MVC5 application

None of these appear to make any change.

Edit: I'm told the server logs don't appear to show anything, but that may be by configuration (I don't have access to them)

Comment: Is there no error in the response text of the 500 error Safari is receiving?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the only response text I can see is 'There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.'

Comment: Very odd. The only difference I could imagine is the `data` coming from the Safari request somehow causes a problem in your server side code. Could you add the code of `buildAddressJsonData()` to the question - or at least check it is generating the object you expect it to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the data appears to be valid JSON, I've updated the question

Comment: Indeed. There's nothing wrong with that at all. Sorry, I don't believe I can be of any more help to you

Comment: Inspect the request and compare it with the browser that works and see what is different. Check the server logs and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution for this is what [Josep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544439/josep) suggested for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587400/angular-get-request-error-but-only-on-safari-ios).

It turns out that Safari on OSX and iOS blocks 3rd party cookies by default and changing this setting fixed this issue.